# error to find in min and max values

Tags: c#

```
    String sql = "select  title, song_id from up_song where Song_type='Mp3 Tracks' ";
    SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, cn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adpt.Fill(ds, "title");
    var m = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().Max(x => x.Field<int>("song_id"));
    var k = ds.Tables["title"].AsEnumerable().Min(x => x.Field<int>("song_id"));
 for (i = m; i >= k; --i)
        {
            try
            {
                hp[i] = new HyperLink();
                hp[i].ID = "hp" + i;
                hp[i].Text = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                hp[i].NavigateUrl = "Downloadpage.aspx";
                hp[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                Panel1.Controls.Add(hp[i]);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
                HttpCookie coo = new HttpCookie("song");
                coo["sogtit"] = ds.Tables["title"].Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString();
                Response.Cookies.Add(coo);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

here i stuck with one error and error is:

There is no row at position 9.There is no row at position 8.There is no row at position 7.

so what is problem in code???

i can not access values from DB what is the another solution thanks?

Comment: Are you sure that this is not a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14811121/284240 ?

Comment: This seems to be almost identical to the question you have asked previously - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14811121/how-i-select-min-and-max-values-from-dataset

Answer (score 0):

If you have SongId 3,4,5,6,7,8,9 in your DB then

```
m is 9

k is 3
```

But your DataTable has only seven rows (0-6). Then you can't access them using the id as row-index.

Comment: no my database has values 1 to 9 and dataset has values 3 to 9 means,if i run code i can get the right value of m and k but then also i did not get right result

Comment: values 3-9 will be on index 0-6 which means that of course index 7,8,9 won't be there. Exactly what I meant with my answer.

Comment: i can not access values .what is the another solution?